# Building Dockerfile fails when touching a file after a mkdir

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and try to build an image with a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN mkdir -pv /home/a/b
RUN touch /home/a/b/test.txt
RUN mkdir -pv /var/jenkins_home/a/b
RUN touch /var/jenkins_home/a/b/test.txt
USER jenkins
```

When I build it, it fails with the following output:

```
Step 0 : FROM jenkins
Step 1 : USER root
Step 2 : RUN mkdir -pv /home/a/b
  mkdir: created directory '/home/a'
  mkdir: created directory '/home/a/b'
Step 3 : RUN touch /home/a/b/test.txt
Step 4 : RUN mkdir -pv /var/jenkins_home/a/b
  mkdir: created directory '/var/jenkins_home/a'
  mkdir: created directory '/var/jenkins_home/a/b'
Step 5 : RUN touch /var/jenkins_home/a/b/test.txt
  touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/a/b/test.txt': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me, what I am missing here? Why does the first mkdir & touch combination work and the second does not?

Comment: Docker 18.09 and BuildKit can help now (April 2019, 4+ years later). See [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31384864/6309)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/jenkins/, it seems that /var/jenkins_home is a volume.  You can only create files there while the container is running, presumably with a volume mapping like

```
docker run ... -v /your/jenkins/home:/var/jenkins_home ...
```

The docker build process knows nothing about shared volumes.

Comment: I think there is a intermediate container running in order to build a image, so can you explain your answer more specifically?

Comment: Edited for more clarity.

Answer (score 6):

This is currently investigated in [docker/docker/issues/3639](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3639#issuecomment-48154253), and summarized in [this comment](http://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3639#issuecomment-48154253):

> Okay, I did little research and **it seems that volume is non-mutable between Dockerfile instruction**.
>   Here even smaller Dockerfile for testing:

```
FROM busybox

RUN mkdir /tmp/volume
RUN echo "hello" > /tmp/volume/hello
VOLUME ["/tmp/volume/"]
RUN [[ -f /tmp/volume/hello ]]
RUN rm /tmp/volume/hello
RUN [[ ! -e /tmp/volume/hello ]]
```

> **On each instruction we create new volume and copy content from original volume**.

[Update April 2019](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3639#issuecomment-481746950):

> Use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`
>   The new builder does not exhibit this behavior.

Example from [`dominikzalewski`](https://github.com/dominikzalewski):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13519572/55938628-13b60580-5c3c-11e9-8096-9ab860198920.png]

> That's a very simple Dockerfile that I'm using:

```
FROM wordpress:latest
ARG UPLOAD_DIR=/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads

RUN mkdir -p $UPLOAD_DIR
RUN ls -lhd $UPLOAD_DIR
```

Cf. **[Build Enhancements for Docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/)**

> **Docker Build enhancements for 18.09 release** introduces a much-needed overhaul of the build architecture.
>   By integrating BuildKit, users should see an improvement on performance, storage management, feature functionality, and security.
>
> - Docker images created with buildkit can be pushed to Docker Hub and DTR just like Docker images created with legacy build
> - The Dockerfile format that works on legacy build will also work with buildkit builds
> - The new `--secret` command line option allows the user to pass secret information for building new images with a specified Dockerfile

Comment: This is a much better answer :)