# Why I can't touch file when the docker image has volume?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a mybase:latest image like this:

```
  FROM     ubuntu:latest                                                                                                                                                                                          
  VOLUME   /var
```

Then I encountered an error when `docker run`:

```
docker run -it mybase:latest  mkdir -p /var/test && touch /var/test/test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/test/test.txt’: No such file or directory
```

I noticed this question: [Building Dockerfile fails when touching a file after a mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469583/building-dockerfile-fails-when-touching-a-file-after-a-mkdir)

But it did not solve my problem as it said:

 `You can only create files there while the container is running`

I think during Docker creating that container, `mkdir -p /var/test && touch /var/test/test.txt` is executed after all the volumes are ready, so it should work.

Where is worry about my thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `&&` part isn't in the same shell as the one created for the container. (But is actually the shell where you type the `docker run` command)

Try:

```
docker run -it mybase:latest  sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/test && touch /var/test/test.txt'
```

That way at least, the `&&` part applies to the shell of the `mkdir` command.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Could u explain the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469583/building-dockerfile-fails-when-touching-a-file-after-a-mkdir? which use RUN but also fails?

Comment: @harryz Sure. I have added an answer there as well.